# Compiling in NASM simple program

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to compile this program using NASM:

```
.model small
.STACK 100h
.data
    no dw 31429
    nstr db 6 dup(' ')
    idv dw 10
.code
.startup
    mov ax, dgroup
    mov ds, ax
    mov si,5
    mov nstr[si], '$'
    dec si
    mov ax, no
    mov dx,0

loop1:
    div idv
    add dl, '0'
    mov nstr[si],dl
    dec si
    mov dx,0
    cmp ax,0
    jne loop1

listn:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset nstr
    int 21h 

stopprg:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
end
```

And here's the output:

```
Afis.asm:6: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
Afis.asm:6: error: parser: instruction expected
Afis.asm:7: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
Afis.asm:7: error: parser: instruction expected
Afis.asm:8: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error
Afis.asm:8: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
Afis.asm:10: error: comma expected after operand 1
Afis.asm:12: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error
Afis.asm:13: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error
Afis.asm:20: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
Afis.asm:37: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
Afis.asm:49: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
Afis.asm:55: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error
```

From what I know the program works fine with DosBOX, as my colleague told me, unfortunately I'm using linux and I cannot understand why I'm getting those errors.
Can someone point out where I'm making errors and how I can fix this?

Comment: The code you have posted is _MASM/TASM_ which is different than _NASM_. It is also MS-DOS code so if you end up compiling it - it will only run in an emulator or virtual machine under Linux.

Comment: If you want to assemble this on Linux and run it in an emulator like Dosbox or DosEMU then you may wish to look at the [JWASM project](https://github.com/JWasm/JWasm) which is a MASM like clone for platforms like Linux.

Comment: [Int 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_API) is [Real Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode). Linux runs in [Protected Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode).